# How to get List<Map<String,Object>> from the result set of Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, dictionary, jpa, jpql

I am using hibernate to get a result like this,

project_id - 123 , 111 , 134 
Count  - 2 , 5 ,6

Here is my Dao layer -

```
@Query("SELECT project_id,COUNT(*) FROM lead_master WHERE vendor_id = ?1 and source = 'share' group by project_id ")
List<Map<String,Object>> getProjectLead(userId);
```

Output - I want the List of Map where the project_id should be the key and the count should be the object associated with that key.so it will be like -

123 - 2 
111 - 5 
134 - 6

Comment: this one either use `List<Object[]>` or projection https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions

Comment: but i want to get a mapped list that will be a pair of project id and count

Comment: even `Object[]` also has same information project_id at `0` and count at `1` indexes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ResultTransformer` for that:

```
(List<Map<String, Object>>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT project_id, COUNT(*) FROM lead_master WHERE vendor_id = :userId and source = 'share' group by project_id "
)
    .setParameter("userId", userId)
    .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
    .setResultTransformer(
        new ResultTransformer() {
            @Override
            public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) { // 2.
                return new HashMap.of((String) tuple[0], tuple[1]);
            }

            @Override
            public List transformList(List collection) {
                return collection;
            }
        }
    )
    .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did simply iterate the list of map from jpa then get the values of project_id,count and then stored the key and values using new map.I hope it will help you.

```
Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> res = samplerepository.getProjectLead(userId);
        res.forEach(action -> {
            String key = (String) action.get("project_id");
            BigInteger value = (BigInteger) action.get("count");                
            map.put(key, value);
        });
        System.out.println("size : " + map.toString());   

        Output will be :: {111=5, 123=2, 134=6}
```

Thanks,